# Apple notarization lists dylib files as not signed

Tags: java, macos, notarize

We distribute a Java application with a bundled JRE, 1.8.0_172. I sign the app using the flags -f --deep and --options runtime. Looking at the CodeResources file in the _CodeSignature directory of the bundled JRE, every file in the JRE is signed and accounted for.

However, after submitting a DMG containing the app to Apple for notarizing, our software is rejected. ALL 60 DYLIB FILES IN THE JRE ARE LISTED AS NOT SIGNED. Here is an example:

From the CodeResources file:

```
<key>Home/jre/lib/libAppleScriptEngine.dylib</key>
    <dict>
        <key>hash</key>
        <data>
        oJjQQGky4LuYNhwuBu8zMLG4zbc=
        </data>
        <key>hash2</key>
        <data>
        grMACw0q7A9GJyPxlSBDGYEkZKrDusKLRRnXsW/bHGI=
        </data>
    </dict>
```

From the response from Apple:

```
"severity": "error",
"code": null,
"path": "TheApplication.dmg/TheApplication.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.8.0_172.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libAppleScriptEngine.dylib",
"message": "The binary is not signed.",
"docUrl": null,
"architecture": "x86_64"
```

In addition to the dylib files, the file jspawnhelper is also rejected as not signed.

Lastly, the file libjli.dylib is rejected for the following reason:
"The binary uses an SDK older than the 10.9 SDK."

Has anyone encountered a similar problem and then been able to pass the notarization process?

January 14, 2020:
The steps I used from this website http://www.zarkonnen.com/signing_notarizing_catalina
do not work as of today. Apple changed their restrictions. I now have the same issues as I first asked about in this post.

**February 21, 2020:**
It turned out the files listed as not signed were in fact not signed. I now use a shell script to recursively sign every file in our application. I follow that with overall signing of the bundled JRE, other internal apps, and lastly the entire app at the top level.

The remaining problem is Java 8 is not built with files that use the hardened runtime. Hopefully OpenJDK and/or AdoptOpenJDK will soon have new versions of Java 8 that satisfy Apple's hardened runtime requirements.

Comment: I was researching the notarizing process for a client today and found your post, along with many other SO threads about signing. My conclusion is that _yes_, all .dylib files have to be signed, which is annoying. I think I will end up building a script that goes through the folder since it is a separate application not built in Xcode.

Comment: "The binary uses an SDK older than the 10.9 SDK." for this you need to manually rebuild it yourself with sdk >=10.9

Comment: Have you tried notarizing a zip of the app first before the dmg?

Comment: Thank you, Richard, for the suggestion. I will submit a zip and see what comes back.

Comment: @PeterHuneke was you able to solve the issue with "The binary uses an SDK older than the 10.9 SDK." and successfully notarize Java 8 app?

Comment: Today I submitted a zip of the app. The app was successfully notarized. I assembled the app using infinitekind-appbundler. The app bundle also includes an Electron app which I previously signed.  I used an ant build file to sign the bundled JRE. Then I signed the overall app. All of this was done on a Mac with High Sierra.

Comment: Turns out although the app was notarized and stapled, the app would not run on Mojave nor Catalina because the JRE was not allowed to run. I modified my process by following the instructions on this site: http://www.zarkonnen.com/signing_notarizing_catalina The main thing I was missing were entitlements. Now my app will run on Catalina and Mojave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Java 8: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8223671

The fastest solution to this problem might come from AdoptOpenJDK hopefully by the end of current month: https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-build/issues/1130

Comment: In addition to using AdoptOpenJDK, it is necessary to individually sign every file in the app. Signing using the --deep flag is not enough. We use a shell script to loop through all of the files and sign them.